# Finding a geodesic on a plane using polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

This is from my homework on PDE.

I need to find a geodesic on a plane using polar coordinates. Now, I know

$dl^2 = x^2+y^2$ hence $l=\int \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$,

but I get stuck while converting coordinates. I guess it's the result of a hole in education. Nevertheless, could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polar coordinates the arc length is given by:
$$l=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[r(\theta)^2+(\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta})^2}d\theta$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain, how do I make this conversion? Or maybe you could point at some good material?

Comment: You can find 'coordinates change' on google. 'http://www.eaeeie.org/theiere/curvilinear/GenCurvilinCoord.htm' is an example.